# How can a gui be visible till all the work is done? (QGIS plugin, python)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, gui

I have made a gui in QTDesigner for QGIS2.10 (as a dialog).
When I press the ok button (if result == QtGui.QFileDialog.Accepted:) everything works just fine but the gui is disappeared.
How can the gui stay there - be visible till all the work is done (it is set to be on top)? 
Do I need something like a timer or should I look for some kind of relative property?

Comment: You can add a simple QPushButton, then connect a function to do the stuff to the clicked signal. At the end of that function just close dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dmh126 said, you can work with signals and events.

Let's say you have a QPushButton called `runButton` labelled as "OK" or anything. Put the following line at the end of the `initGui` function:

> `self.dlg.runButton.clicked.connect( self.onStart )`

(replacing `dlg` with whatever applies to you).

The declare a `onStart` function that will call your main function :

> `@pyqtSlot()`
>   `def onStart(self):`
>   `...`

That should do the trick.